# LinkList node skips the loop and move to further next parameter

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying to practise leetcode example.
Input - 
[2,4,3]
[5,6,4]

Expected Output is = [7,0,8]; (2+5 , 4+6 , 3+4+1(carry over 1 from node 2));
What i am getting is [7,8];

q.next and p.next - skips the addition of 2nd node and only do addition for 1st and 3rd node.
I am not able to understand why 2nd node is skipped.

```
public class ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode next;
    ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
}

class Solution {
    public ListNode addTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
        ListNode extra = new ListNode(0);
        ListNode p = l1 , q = l2, curr = extra;
        int carry = 0;
        while(p != null || q != null)
        {
            int x = (p != null) ? p.val :0 ;
            int y = (q != null) ? q.val :0 ;
            int sum = carry + x + y ;
            carry = sum / 10;
            curr.next = new ListNode(sum % 10);
            p=p.next;
            q=q.next;
            if(p != null)p = p.next;
            if(q != null)q = q.next;
        }
        if(carry > 0)
        {
            curr.next = new ListNode(carry);
        }
        return curr;
    }
}
```

**EDITED AS PER THE ANSWERS** - i checked below code in leetcode. It still says output is [0,8]
instead of [7,0,8]

here is the link of the problem : https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers/

```
class Solution {
    public ListNode addTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
          ListNode extra = new ListNode(0);
        ListNode p = l1 , q = l2, curr = extra;
        int carry = 0;
        while(p != null || q != null)
        {
            int x = (p != null) ? p.val :0 ;
            int y = (q != null) ? q.val :0 ;
            int sum = carry + x + y ;
            carry = sum / 10;
            curr.next = new ListNode(sum % 10);

            if(p != null)p = p.next;
            if(q != null)q = q.next;
        }
        if(carry > 0)
        {
            curr.next = new ListNode(carry);
        }
        return curr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: p = p.next; if (p != null) p = p.next;  You're skipping a node here, same with q.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. As already mentionned in other answers, `p` and `q` are advanced twice in each iteration (with the risk of a `NullPointerException` BTW).
2. Also, `curr` is never advanced, so `extra.next` is overwritten at each iteration.
3. Your method returns `curr` that points to the last element of the list at the end of the method. Try returning `extra.next` instead (or `extra` if it's `null` and you need at least one element).

   ```
   ListNode extra = new ListNode(0);
   ListNode p = l1 , q = l2, curr = extra;
   int carry = 0;
   while(p != null || q != null)
   {
       int x = (p != null) ? p.val :0 ;
       int y = (q != null) ? q.val :0 ;
       int sum = carry + x + y ;
       carry = sum / 10;
       curr.next = new ListNode(sum % 10);
       curr = curr.next;
       if(p != null)p = p.next;
       if(q != null)q = q.next;
   }
   if(carry > 0)
   {
       curr.next = new ListNode(carry);
   }
   return extra.next == null ? extra : extra.next;
   ```

Answer (score 3):

You have a redundant

```
p = p.next 
q = q.next
```

which results in skipping odd indices (0 based). This should be removed, as only

```
if(p != null)p = p.next;
if(q != null)q = q.next;
```

would suffice

Comment: I tried this and edited my question. Please check it is still not working

Answer (score 3):

You increment both the `ListNode`'s pointer more than you should. In this part:

```
    while(p != null || q != null)
    {
        int x = (p != null) ? p.val :0 ;
        int y = (q != null) ? q.val :0 ;
        int sum = carry + x + y ;
        carry = sum / 10;
        curr.next = new ListNode(sum % 10);
        p=p.next; /* You increment the pointers right after this */
        q=q.next;
        if(p != null)p = p.next; // You don't even need this if statement either, thats what the while loop checks.
        if(q != null)q = q.next;
    }
```

Also, you should put `while(p != null && q != null)` instead of `||`, and then put any remaining value after you get outside the loop.

If you want you can look at my solution: https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers/discuss/519946/Java-Simple

Comment: Right. Good catch on both problems.

Comment: I tried this and edited my question. Please check it is still not working

Comment: Because I said you have to put an && instead of ||, and then put any extra numbers afterward.

Comment: Because you have to put an && instead of || in the while loop, and add any non-null numbers afterwards. Look at my solution to see what I mean.